# jQuery focus after element removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some contenteditable paragraphs that I would like to remove if the delete or backspace key is pressed. I've written the following script for this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'p[contenteditable="true"]', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).after('<p contenteditable = "true">New Paragraph</p>');
        $(this).next('p').focus();
    } else if((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).text() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).remove();
        $(this).previous('p').focus();
    };
});
```

I would like to focus on the previous paragraph after removal but I don't believe I can do this as `this` no longer exists. I've also tried putting the `focus` before `remove` however it appears to change the value of `this`.

Comment: Name of the method is `prev` not `previous`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'p[contenteditable="true"]', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).after('<p contenteditable = "true">New Paragraph</p>');
        $(this).next('p').focus();
    } else if((e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) && $(this).text() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        var prev = $(this).prev('p');
        $(this).remove();
        prev.focus();
    };
});
```

Also worth noting that `.previous()` is not a jQuery method, I believe the method you are looking for is [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)